# How to script an interactive NPC having dialogue and menus in LUA with C++?

Tags: c++, lua, client-server, game-engine, game-development

I'm working on a 2D game engine in C++ and have thought about moving the NPC scripts such as dialogues and menu selection items into LUA. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to wait for a response from the user/client. My scenario is as follows -

1. User clicks on NPC.
2. NPC initiates a dialogue window, player cannot move. LUA script is read and started to run. Example:

```
mes("Hello! " .. PlayerName)
next()
reply = select("Would you like to do this?", "Or that?")
if reply == 1 then
   mes("You chose: Or that!")
   close()
end
```

Now, I want the script to send one message `mes` at a time, and the next() function would send a next button to the client. After which the script pauses and waits for the user's input.
Once the next button is clicked, the script continues, sending a menu to the client. Upon selection it further continues into the conditional clause or not, depending on the selection.

All this is server sided and the dialogues are sent to the client. What I want to achieve is a pause functionality while waiting for the client's response.

What would be a good way to achieve this in Lua? If you have suggestions for best practices I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, but what I do is I yield the execution (`coroutine.yield()` on the Lua side).  On the C side, the `lua_resume` then returns whatever you passed to `coroutine.yield()` as parameter. When you got your response on the C side, call `lua_resume` again and pass the response, which on the Lua side is received as the return value of `coroutine.yield()`. You can check if the script yielded by looking at the return value of `lua_resume`, it is `LUA_YIELD` if it yielded and `0` if it finished successfully.

Comment: As @Blaze said coroutines are very good for this task. This [blog](https://eliasdaler.github.io/how-to-implement-action-sequences-and-cutscenes/) has some good explanations for exact your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll agree with @Blaze and go with coroutines as my answer. The question would then be, when and how to wrap Lua scripts into coroutines.

Just wrapping every script into its own coroutine *might** lose you some performance, but if most of your scripts are longer than just a few lines, this should not be very noticeable. Aside from speed concerns you'd have to keep in mind that in [5.1](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-coroutine.running) `coroutine.running()` would then not return `nil` even in the top level of the script, because that's also just a coroutine. In [5.3](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-coroutine.running) this is less of a problem, as it always returns a thread plus a boolean.

* You'll need to benchmark if this is at all relevant

The next big question would be whether to do the wrapping in Lua or in C(++). Lua is obviously more flexible and easier to change, but C might gain you some performance, which is rarely as relevant as when developing games. The obvious downside being that the C API is just more inconvenient to use.

The most important issue though, is that you couldn't (or shouldn't) just implement, for example, `next()` as just a wrapper around `coroutine.yield('next')` or something like that, because you may have nested coroutines; so you'd need some more logic around that to pass through your API calls to the top level and then to C++.

I hope this gives you a good overview of the most important considerations when deciding whether or not to go with coroutines for this problem.